# Hover Icons in a Table devexpress

Tags: c#, grid, blazor, devexpress

I'd like to show icon  on each row I hover over in my table. I've managed to make a background appear but not an icon. i program in blazor (c#) and i use devexpress.
here is the full page :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />

@using DeleteSelectedRows.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <DxButton Text="@GetButtonText()" Click="@ToggleEditMode" />
    </div>

    <DxGrid @ref="myGrid" Data="@forecasts" CssClass="mw-1100" CustomizeElement="OnCustomizeElement" @bind-SelectedDataItems="@selectedDataItems" KeyFieldName="ID">
        <Columns>
            @if (isEditMode)
            {
                <DxGridSelectionColumn VisibleIndex="0" Width="50px"/>
            }
            <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Date" FieldName="Date" />
            <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Temperature (F)" FieldName="TemperatureF" />
            <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Temperature (C)" FieldName="TemperatureC" />
            <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Summary" FieldName="Summary"/>
        </Columns>
    </DxGrid>
    @if (selectedDataItems != null && selectedDataItems.Count > 0)
    {
        <DxButton Text="Delete" Click="@OnClick" />
    }

    <style>
        .highlighted-item:hover, .highlighted-item:hover > td {
            background-color: coral;
        }
    </style>
}

@code {
    IGrid myGrid { get; set; }
    List<WeatherForecast> forecasts;
    IReadOnlyList<object> selectedDataItems { get; set; }
    bool isEditMode = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }

    void OnClick(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        if (selectedDataItems != null)
        {
            foreach (WeatherForecast row in selectedDataItems)
            forecasts.Remove(row);
            selectedDataItems = null;
            myGrid.Reload();
        }
    }

    void ToggleEditMode(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        isEditMode = !isEditMode;
        if (!isEditMode)
        {
            selectedDataItems = null;
        }
        myGrid.Reload();
    }

    string GetButtonText()
    {
        return isEditMode ? "Unlocked" : "Locked";
    }

    void OnCustomizeElement(GridCustomizeElementEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ElementType == GridElementType.DataRow)
            e.CssClass = "highlighted-item";
    }
}
```

i tryed to use chatgpt, stackoverflow, codepen.io github but i didn't found someone else with the same problem. i wanted to have the same result when you open gmail. Because in gmail if you want to delete or archive a message you just need to hover the email that you want to manage and that's it.